# merge try catch in java 8

Tags: java, try-catch

I am new to java 8.

Following is my code,

```
File file = new File("C:\\abc\\def\\ghi"); //def, ghi doesnot exists
file.mkdirs();
try {
    file.createNewFile(); //throw IOE
} catch (IOE ioe) {
}  
try (BufferedOutputStream stream = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));) {
       //some logic
} catch (IOE ioe) {
}
```

How I can merge/refactor two try-catch in java 8 way.

Comment: Beware that `file.mkdirs();` will create the directory `C:\abc\def\ghi`, so any attempt to create a file `C:\abc\def\ghi` afterwards will fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for this?

```
File file = new File("C:\\abc\\def\\ghi"); //def, ghi doesnot exists
file.mkdirs();
try {
    file.createNewFile(); //throw IOE
    BufferedOutputStream stream = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file)));
       //some logic
} catch (IOE ioe) {
       // handleException
}
```

Comment: Note that this doesn't currently close the stream; you should still use try-with-resources inside.

Comment: yes, this I know but want to know how to use resource inside try(....) and both in same try catch

Comment: You should use finally block to close open file handle and  stream.

Comment: that means for "file" object i have to manually close it in finally. Java wont do that?

Comment: @sillyquestions No Java do not Close the file automatically

Comment: File file = new File("C:\\abc\\def\\ghi"); //def, ghi doesnot exists
        file.mkdirs();
        BufferedOutputStream stream = null;
        try {
            file.createNewFile(); //throw IOE
            stream = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));
               //some logic
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
               // handleException
        } finally {
            if (stream != null)
               stream.close();
        }

Comment: @DhananjayKashyap don't reinvent wheels. Try-with-resources does this, better.

Answer (score 2):

It depends upon what you mean by "merge".

If you simply mean having a single `catch` block, that's easy: just move the second `try` inside the first:

```
File file = new File("C:\\abc\\def\\ghi"); //def, ghi doesnot exists
file.mkdirs();
try {
    file.createNewFile(); //throw IOE
    try (BufferedOutputStream stream = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file))) {
       //some logic
    }
} catch (IOE ioe) {
    // Common handling of IOE.
}
```

I wouldn't try to merge it any further; the second/inner `try` has the semantics of closing the stream. This is a good thing, and requires a `try` block to do.

Comment: like BufferedOutputStream java do auto handling but for "file" I have to close it manually or it not required to close "file"?

Comment: You can't close a `File`; you need to close the `FileOutputStream`.

Answer (score -1):

```
File file = new File("C:\\abc\\def\\ghi"); //def, ghi doesnot exists
file.mkdirs();
BufferedOutputStream stream = null;
try {
     file.createNewFile(); //throw IOE
     stream = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));
                   //some logic
} catch (IOException ioe) {
                // handleException
} finally {
       if (stream != null)
       stream.close();
}
```

You can use like this.

Comment: Try-with-resources does the closing of the stream more concisely, and with better error handling.